# How to replace imports in imported library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, python-importlib

Suppose, we have 3 files:

library1.py:

```
SomeVariable = '1'
```

library2.py:

```
import library1
print(library1.SomeVariable)
```

library3.py:

```
SomeVariable = '2'
```

my goal is to "change" library1 import(not only 1 variable) in library2.py so result output will be '2'
(in other words,replace cache of library1 in library2.py to library3)

Comment: what have you tried so far and what error you are facing

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question at the moment. Are you trying to overwrite variables inside of `library1.py`, and then use those overwritten variables in `library3.py`?

Comment: @EricJin i want to overwrite the whole library1 in library2

Comment: So, say, if we have library1 with `mynumber = 1; myletter = 'b'; mystring = 'qwerty'`, and then library3 is `myletter = 'c'; mystring = 'No.'` you want to import `mynumber = 1; myletter = 'c'; mystring = 'No.'`?

Comment: @EricJin yes,all variables,but not manually

Comment: @EricJin
For example,I can do that
lib1: ```a=1;b=2```
lib2: ```import lib1;print(lib1.a+lib1.b)```
lib3:```a = 2;b = 3```
main.py: ```import importlib,lib1,lib2,lib3; lib1.a,lib1.b = lib3.a,lib3.b;importlib.reload(lib2) ```- but I do not want to update all variables manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### WARNING: This method is *very* hacky, and you <del>might</del> probably will break things.

---

Let's say we have this `library1.py`:

```py
var1 = 100
var2 = 'never gonna give you up'
a = 3.1415926
```

And, we want to overwrite it with `overwrite.py`:

```py
var1 = -9999
var2 = 'never gonna let you down'
a = 2.71828
```

---

If we go into a shell, we can see that a module has a `__dict__` attribute that holds everything it has inside of it.

```py
>>> import library1
>>> library1.__dict__
# NOTE: This also contains a bunch of python's variables, including their builtins, magic things like `__name__`, etc
# I cut them out for simplicity
{'var1': 100, 'var2': 'never gonna give you up', 'a': 3.1415926}
```

This is nice, since we can use this to access the attributes without really accessing them:

```py
>>> import library1
>>> library1.__dict__['a'] = 'never gonna run around and desert you'
>>> library1.a
'never gonna run around and desert you'
>>> library1.__dict__['this_variable_wasnt_even_defined'] = 'never gonna make you cry'
>>> library1.this_variable_wasnt_even_defined
'never gonna make you cry'
```

---

We don't want to overwrite any magic (starting and ending with two underscores) attributes, so:

```py
>>> def is_magic(name: str) -> bool:
...     return name[0] == '_' and name[1] == '_' and name[-1] == '_' and name[-2] == '_'

>>> is_magic('not_very_magic_variable')
False
>>> is_magic('__name__')
True
>>> is_magic('__init__')
True
```

We also don't want to overwrite any builtin functions:

```py
>>> def is_builtin(obj: object) -> bool:
...     builtin_type = type(print)
...     return obj.__class__ is builtin_type
... 

>>> is_builtin(print)
True
>>> is_builtin(open)
True
```

---

This is where it all comes together.

We use values in `library3` to overwrite the `__dict__` of `library1`.

```
>>> from utils import is_builtin, is_magic
>>> import library1
>>> import overwrite
>>> 
>>> for key, value in overwrite.__dict__.items():
...     if is_magic(key):
...         continue
...     if is_builtin(value):
...         continue
...     # otherwise, we have something to overwrite
...     library1.__dict__[key] = value
...     print(f'I have overwritten {key} with {value}')
... 
I have overwritten var1 with -9999
I have overwritten var2 with never gonna let you down
I have overwritten a with 2.71828
```

You can see that `library1` has been overwritten:

```py
# ...
>>> library1.var1
-9999
>>> library1.var2
'never gonna let you down'
>>> library1.a
2.71828
```

Comment: Yep,thats I want to see
Thank you)

Comment: but if you want to use ONLY vars,that overwrite contains ,you can simply do:```library1.__dict__ = overwrite.__dict__```

Comment: @IlyaBatkov You probably don't want to do that, because now they point to the same object, and you have magically linked together both of them.

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to do that:

```
import library1,library2,library3
import importlib

for i in library3.__dict__.keys():
    library1.__dict__[i] = library3.__dict__[i]
library2 = importlib.reload(library2)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use copy

```
import copy
b = copy.copy(lib1.a)
...
print(lib2.b)
```

Comment: can you explain how using a copy here help?

Comment: For that trick you dont need to use copy
my goal is to change b inside lib2,not in main.py

Comment: If I understand he's having some trouble with vars use, the copy allow to do a  copy of var value and not reference copy. The sample does not have any information in ..<some magic>...

Comment: @IlyaBatkov but you print lib2.b -> 2 because you assign a=2 in lib3? What code are before print?

Comment: @MarioCerónCharry I asking help for that)
<some magic> - means idk what happens here

Comment: @IlyaBatkov sorry, but the question is not clear and I answer based on the published code. Please edit your question.

Comment: @MarioCerónCharry Ok,I try to explain more details

Comment: @MarioCerónCharry can you check my question now,please?